# C# Printing inconsistent from same application to same printer on different workstations

Tags: c#, printing, system.drawing

It seems like there should be more information on this, but I can't seem to find the right words to search by.

Basically, I have a C# application that prints off a filled out form. I take user input and draw them over a image of the form then print it off. This application works perfectly for all but one of the workstations that use it.

The text on the form doesn't print in the correct location, rather it seems to be offset by and additional .25" on the x and y axis while the image of the form prints of perfectly. All workstations print to the same shared printer and use the same application.

I'm not sure what settings would cause the printer to print the text in a different location.

Is there a way to configure my application or the users workstation so I won't need to created a "personalized" version of the application for that workstation?

Thank you for help.

Comment: One thing that comes to mind are different printer drivers on the machines. Another is, that maybe you didn't set the output's dpi resolution? If you don't, different display resolutions might mess things up..

Comment: That may be it, I will look into setting the output dpi resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find the reason in different drivers or resolutions, an alternative might be to generate a PDF and then send that to the printer. That way you have control of the output page and can preview it as well. There are many libraries for generating PDF files. If you're generating HTML, you can use the free wkhtmltopdf to convert from HTML to PDF. I'm sure there are many others as well. Good luck!